# unicode-math: Use text font for numerical digits in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math

Using XeTeX with `fontspec` and `unicode-math`, I would like to use the documents main font for for *digits* (numbers) in mathmode. Also, I would like to make `\text{}` in mathmode use Lining numbers while the default for the document are OldStyle numbers. How can I achieve this behavior?

I tried inserting `\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num}]{Linux Libertine O}` but it does not give the desired result.

Here is an MWE, pointing out the problems:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O} 

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
% Here I try to set up the normal text font for digits in mathmode: 
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num}]{Linux Libertine O}

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

This is \ifXeTeX XeTeX\fi\ifLuaTeX LuaTeX\fi 
with \fontname\font
\bigskip

Text numbers: 
0123456789; italic: \textit{0123456789}; bold: \textbf{0123456789} 

Text numbers lining: 
\liningnums{0123456789; italic: \textit{0123456789}; bold: 
\textbf{0123456789}}

Numbers in mathmode: $0123456789$ (ok)\\
mathit: $\mathit{0123456789}$ (wrong font)\\
mathbf: $\mathbf{0123456789}$ (wrong font)\\
mathrm: $\mathrm{0123456789}$ (wrong font)\\
text (math): $\text{0123456789}$ (should be lining)

In big equation, fonts for big brackets $\big( \Big( \bigg( \Bigg($ are
missing: 
\[
\left(\frac{12a}{34b}\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

Using XeTeX, this results in:

[image]

So there are 3 problems:

1. `Linux Libertine O` for digits does not appear in `\mathrm`, `\mathit`, and `\mathbf` etc.
2. The big brackets are not working. (See more on this below.)
3. Is there a way to achieve Lining numbers in mathmode `\text{}` although the document number style is OldStyle?

Concerning problem 1, this is due to `range=\mathup/{num}` only applying to updright math text. Does anyone know how to apply this command for all numerals in all ranges? using only `range={num}` results in an error.

Concerning problem 2, I have two more pieces of information. A) Using LuaTeX on the same file, the brackets *do appear*, but without being scaled:

[image]

B) If I comment out the line `\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num}]{Linux Libertine O}`, the problem does not occur at all. This suggests that the bracket mechanism is affected by changing the font for numbers, which it shouldn't be, right?

[image]

This problem is, by the way, not specific to `Linux Libertine O`. It also appeared when I was using `SabonNextLTPro` as main document font.

Comment: `unicode-math` is somewhat buggy. In particular, the `range` stuff does not work as advertised. I think you have to think of it as a work in progress ....

Comment: Yeah sure, I figured that from the manual :) But I was wondering, is there a hack to map only 0123456789 and not also other signs such as brackets to a different font?

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime until anybody might come up with an idea, I though I'd share a workaround. It's basically reverting to `mathspec` instead of `unicode-math`. Nearly everything works out of the box in only three lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} 
\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O} 

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathfont(Digits){Linux Libertine O}

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

This is \ifXeTeX XeTeX\fi\ifLuaTeX LuaTeX\fi 
with \fontname\font
\bigskip

Text numbers: 
0123456789; italic: \textit{0123456789}; bold: \textbf{0123456789} 

Text numbers lining: 
\liningnums{0123456789; italic: \textit{0123456789}; bold: 
\textbf{0123456789}}

Numbers in mathmode: $0123456789$ (ok)\\
mathit: $\mathit{0123456789}$ (correct font but no italic)\\
mathbf: $\mathbf{0123456789}$ (correct font but no boldface)\\
mathrm: $\mathrm{0123456789}$ (ok)\\
text (math): $\text{0123456789}$ (should be lining)

In equations, testing fonts for big brackets $\big( \Big( \bigg( \Bigg($: 
\[
\left(\frac{12a}{34b}\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]